# Is there a way to dynamically set an element name in angular template?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am not talking about HTML forms here or element attributes named "name".

I am wondering if there is a way to conditionally choose the output HTML element name when using angular templates?

Essentially, I want to do this:

```
<ng-container *ngElementName="href() ? 'a' : 'span'" [routerLink]="href()">{{ caption() }}</ng-container>
```

With the expected output, when `href()` returns something:

```
<a href="/href-location">href supplied, caption</a>
```

And this, when `href()` returns noting:

```
<span href="">href missing, caption</span>
```

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about not using a function but you can do it with an ngIf. You cannot put a href on a span.

```
<a [href]="href()" *ngIf="href()">href supplied, caption</a>
<span *ngIf="!href()">href missing, caption</span>
```

or use a template so you don't call the href() function too many times.

```
<ng-content *ngIf="href() as href else noHref">
  <a [href]="href">href supplied, caption</a>
</ng-content>
<ng-template #noHref>
  <span>href missing, caption</span>
</ng-template>
```

or create a component that take a href as an input property and does the above inside the components template, if you are repeating this in many places then it will save you repeating markup.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-link',
  templateUrl: './link.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./link.component.css']
})
export class LinkComponent {
  @Input()
  href: string;
}
```

with a template

```
<a [href]="href" *ngIf="href"><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container></a>
<span *ngIf="!href"><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container></span>
<ng-template #content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

and use it like

```
<app-link [href]="href()">caption</app-link>
```

Comment: It used inside a *ngFor loop so I would have to pass loop variable inside the template, and also the "body" is quite large, So I would have to template it out too... suddenly, a simple concept turns out as big and ugly pice of code. Hard to read and maintain. I was hoping there is a trick I am missing which would allow me to do that neatly.

Comment: Then the component option is for you.